# LEFT JOIN is not returning the correct result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables one for the parties and the other for the guests.

The first table was created with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `party` (
  `party_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `details` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`party_id`)
)
```

the second table has the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `guests` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `party_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`party_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index2` (`user_id`,`party_id`),
  KEY `fk_idx` (`party_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`party_id`) REFERENCES `party` (`party_id`)
)
```

Now I want with one statement to get from a subset of parties (using IN statement maybe) which parties the guest have attended or did not attended at all.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
party.party_id, party.details, 
guests.user_id, guests.name
FROM party
LEFT JOIN guests
ON party.party_id = guests.party_id 
where 
party.party_id IN (1,2,3) 
and (guests.user_id=23123 or guests.user_id is null) ORDER BY party.party_id;
```

The problem with this query is that returns me back only the row where user 23123 did not participate and nobody else did.

[image]

I would like to have in the result set parties 1,2 and 3 since user 23123 did not participate.
How is this done right?

Some insert data that might help to debug the problem:

```
INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('1', 'nice party');
INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('2', 'pizza');
INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('3', 'end');
INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('4', 'party four');
INSERT INTO `party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('5', 'secret');
INSERT INTO ``party` (`party_id`, `details`) VALUES ('6', 'downtown');


INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('100', 'u100', '1');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('101', 'u101', '1');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('102', 'u102', '1');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('200', 'u200', '2');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('100', 'u100', '2');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('100', 'u100', '6');
INSERT INTO `guests` (`user_id`, `name`, `party_id`) VALUES ('500', 'u500', '6');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering on the *second* table should be in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.party_id, p.details, g.user_id, g.name
FROM party p LEFT JOIN
     guests g
     ON p.party_id = g.party_id AND g.user_id = 23123
WHERE p.party_id IN (1,2,3) 
ORDER BY p.party_id;
```

Comment: Great worked. That means that the rows that will be returned will be always equal with the party_ids that will be in the IN clause, if those ids exist at the parties table.